# Getting recv() error on select call to Snowflake database

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I don't have a trimmed set of code to give to reproduce this, nor am I sure I could do that with
without the volume of data that we have.

A select query I have takes 3+ minutes.  It tries to retrieve about 130k worth of records with about 15 columns.  To make things faster, I split the request into separate threads, each fetching about 15k.  The plan is to consolidate the results into a CSV or a .XLS file later.

Some threads finish and apparently get valid data, other times it fails with the message below.

This being Snowflake, I'm sure this works differently than the Oracle database I came from.  Is there a maximum number of connections I'm allowed?  I read somewhere else that it's related to heap size, but I increased my max heap to -Xmx8g.  That probably helped, somehow, but I'm still getting the error.

It would be great if someone here had the answer to my problem.  However, even if someone knows what to look for, it would be helpful.

```
Jul 20, 2020 12:56:25 AM net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: I/O exception (net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://sfc-va-ds1-3-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443: The target server failed to respond

Jul 20, 2020 12:56:35 AM net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://sfc-va-ds1-3-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443

Jul 20, 2020 12:56:25 AM net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: I/O exception (net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://sfc-va-ds1-3-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443: The target server failed to respond

Jul 20, 2020 12:56:35 AM net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://sfc-va-ds1-3-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443

Jul 20, 2020 12:56:25 AM net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: I/O exception (net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://sfc-va-ds1-3-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443: The target server failed to respond

Jul 20, 2020 12:56:35 AM net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://sfc-va-ds1-3-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443

Jul 20, 2020 12:56:35 AM net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://sfc-va-ds1-3-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Jul 20, 2020 12:56:35 AM net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute

INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://sfc-va-ds1-3-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443
```

Comment: I am struggling with this same problem, and I cannot even reproduce it locally. But sadly it happens quite consistently in our kube cluster on a specific dataset :(

Comment: @NikoNyrh I wish I had better info almost a year later but that problem never got truly resolved before I left. If memory serves, having a larger cluster did help.

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost the whole week debugging a similar issue. I'm running the JVM from openjdk:15 docker image with default settings, and apparently its default GC is not the G1GC. So in my case loading data from Snowflake generated so many temporary variables and so fast that the GC had to pause everything for 10 - 20 seconds every minute or so. The G1GC is able to handle the load with fewer long pauses. So enable GC logs via `-verbose:gc` to see whether you are affected by this.

This was difficult to reproduce locally since my internet isn't as fast as when running the code on AWS EKS and loading from S3.

I also learned that Kubernetes was restarting my pods due to long GC pauses, during which it wouldn't respond to the `/health` API end-point.

Comment: Hey Snowflake support, can you please pay attention to these problems!!!